# RaspberryPi - Audio live playback and record to a flac file

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie

I'm trying:
1) record audio via arecord
2) live playback using aplay
3) convert the recorded audio to .flac using flac

Is it possible to perform all three actions simultaneously with the pipe command on command line?

The command i'm trying to use is:

```
arecord -D plughw:0,0 -d 5 -r 16 -f S16_LE | aplay -f S16_LE | flac - -f --best --sample-rate 16000 -o file.flac
```

I'm getting this as the error message:

Recording WAVE 'stdin' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 16000 Hz, Mono
Playing WAVE 'stdin' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 16000 Hz, Mono
ERROR: for encoding a raw file you must specify a value for --endian, --sign, --channels, --bps, and --sample-rate

On adding the recommended values

```
arecord -D plughw:0,0 -d 5 -r 16 -f S16_LE | aplay -f S16_LE | flac - -f --best --sample-rate 16000 --endian little --sign signed --channels 1 --bps 16 -o file.flac
```

This is the output I get:
Recording WAVE 'stdin' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 16000 Hz, Mono
Playing WAVE 'stdin' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 16000 Hz, Mono
(No runtime statistics possible; please wait for encoding to finish...)

```
soxi file.flac
```

Input File     : 'file.flac'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 16000
Precision      : 16-bit
Sample Encoding: 16-bit FLAC

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `tee` command to get this to work. Try something like

`arecord -D plughw:0,0 -d 5 -r 16 -f S16_LE | tee >(aplay -f S16_LE) | flac - -f --best --sample-rate 16000 -o file.flac`

This should redirect the record output into aplay and flac using some redirection.

Comment: If that's working it's wonderful. I hope we'll get some news from the OP :)!